# <<Wavelets`Wavelets Not Found

Tags: packages, wavelet-analysis

please i'm a student and i need help in my project which is based on an already existing program.
The problem that the program is ancient( Mathematica 5.0) and doesn't fit with the new versions of mathematica.
I succeeded to get the old version 5.0 but problem is that the package " wavelets " is not found and in the new versions is pre-defined.
Can any one help me with searching that package or how to get it( for example will it work if i install an old version of matlab) ???

Comment: Evidently the old [Wavelet Explorer](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/applications/wavelet/) is discontinued.  Can you figure out if the newer built-in [Wavelet Analysis](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Wavelets.html) functionality replaces it?

Comment: There is even a conversion [tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Compatibility/tutorial/WaveletExplorer.html) for old WaveletExplorer package.

Answer (score 4):

The old [Wavelet Explorer](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/applications/wavelet/) has been discontinued. The newer built-in [Wavelet Analysis](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Wavelets.html) functionality replaces it, with a conversion tutorial [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Compatibility/tutorial/WaveletExplorer.html).